# Show that $\omega$ is a $C^{\infty}$ - linear map

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ be a $1-$ form on a smooth manifold $M$. Let $\chi(M) $ be the vector space of $C^{\infty}$ vector fields on $M$. Then I need to show that $\omega : \chi(M) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M) $ given as $\omega(X)(p) = \omega_p(X_p)$ ; $p \in M , X \in \chi(M)$ defines a $C^{\infty}$ - linear map. ($\omega_p$ is the co-vector at $p$).

Now I know that I need to show the following -  $$\omega(fX + gY) = f \omega(X) + g \omega(Y)$$ for $X , Y \in \chi(M) $ and $f,g \in C^{\infty}(M)$.

But I am not getting any idea on how to prove the last expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate that expression to the point $p\in M$, so we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\omega_p(fX + gY)_p =&\omega_p(f(p)X_p + g(p)Y_p)\\=&f(p)\omega_p(X_p) + g(p)\omega_p(Y_p)\\=&f(p)\omega(X)(p)+g(p)\omega(Y)(p)
\end{split}\end{equation}

(I used the linearity of the functional $\omega_p$ in the second line), but this is true for any $p\in M$, so we have:
\begin{equation}
\omega(fX + gY) =f\omega(X)+g\omega(Y)
\end{equation}

Comment: You are using the simple fact that forms are by definition $k-linear$ right?

Comment: @Hawk Just to clarify your statement;-)... I'm using the fact that a form is a global section of the cotangent bundle, i.d., a map: $\omega: M\to T^*M$; this defines a co-vector field  that is, for any point of M there is an associated co-vector, so if you think to $\omega$ evaluated in a point $p\in M$, you'll get an element of the cotangent space $T^*_pM$ (a co-vector) that is linear by definition.